# Memory Error in C struct

Tags: c, memory

The following code causes a memory error in the insert_edge function (in the line p->next = g->edges[x] I guess) for large MAXV values. For smaller ones it works great. Where is the problem? How can I define the struct that it works?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE (1024*128)


#define MAXV        23947347        /* maximum number of vertices */
#define NULLO              0        /* null pointer */


#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

typedef int bool;

typedef struct edgenode {
    int y;              /* adjancency info */
    int weight;         /* edge weight, if any */
    struct edgenode *next;      /* next edge in list */
} edgenode;


typedef struct {
    edgenode *edges[MAXV+1];    /* adjacency info */
    int degree[MAXV+1];     /* outdegree of each vertex */
    int nvertices;          /* number of vertices in the graph */
    int nedges;         /* number of edges in the graph */
    int directed;           /* is the graph directed? */
} graph;

initialize_graph(graph *g, bool directed)
{
    int i;              /* counter */

    g -> nvertices = 0;
    g -> nedges = 0;
    g -> directed = directed;

    for (i=1; i<=MAXV; i++) 
            g->degree[i] = 0;
    for (i=1; i<=MAXV; i++) 
            g->edges[i] = NULL;
}

read_graph(graph *g, bool directed, const char *filename)
{

    FILE *f;
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE], buf[10];
    int format, rc;
    int edge; 
    int vertex_n;
    int vertex_m;

    char *token,*token2, *s;

    int v;

    int i;              /* counter */

    /* open file */
    f = fopen (filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
        return NULL;


    rc = sscanf (line, "%d %d %d", &(vertex_n), &(vertex_m), &(edge));

    initialize_graph(g, directed);

    for (i=1; i<=edge; i++) {
         s = fgets (line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, f); 

         token = strtok (line, " ");

         token2 = strtok (NULL, " ");

         int s = atoi(token);
         int t = atoi(token2);

         printf("%d, %d\n", start, ziel);

         insert_edge(g,s,t,directed);

 }

}

insert_edge(graph *g, int x, int y, bool directed)
{
    edgenode *p;            /* temporary pointer */

    p = malloc(sizeof(edgenode));   /* allocate storage for edgenode */

    p->weight = NULL;
    p->y = y;
    p->next = g->edges[x];
        g->edges[x];

    g->edges[x] = p;        /* insert at head of list */

    g->degree[x] ++;

    if (directed == FALSE)
        insert_edge(g,y,x,TRUE);
    else
        g->nedges ++;
 }

    main()
    {
        graph g;

        read_graph(&g,FALSE, "/path/graph_with_23947347_nodes.mtx");//  
    }
```

Comment: K&R C? You'd better switch to ANSI.

Comment: How large are your "large MAXV" values?

Comment: Check that parameter x is not out of bound (MAXV)

Comment: You are not in Fortran, array index start at 0

Comment: @DanielKozar: That's not K&R C. Actually it is neiter K&R C, nor ANSI nor ISO. OP should get a book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
graph g;
```

`graph` is definitively too big to fit on the stack. Put it in the heap instead:

```
graph* g=malloc(sizeof(graph));
```

And follow Graham's advice too. It may be too big even for the heap.

Comment: I have enough memory ;) But this was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it may be a stack overflow. `graph` is a large data structure and you are allocating it locally (i.e. on the stack) in `main`. Try changing main to:

```
int main(void)
{
    graph *g = malloc(sizeof(graph));
    if (g != NULL)
    {
        read_graph(g, FALSE, "/path/graph_with_23947347_nodes.mtx");
        free(g);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking the return value from this `malloc`?

```
p = malloc(sizeof(edgenode));   /* allocate storage for edgenode */
```

It could be that you are simply running out of memory. Check that `p` is not `NULL` before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

```
p->next = g->edges[x];
        g->edges[x];

    g->edges[x] = p;        /* insert at head of list */
```

This code doesn't make any sense.

In a single-linked list, you cannot insert a new node *before* an existing node, without having a pointer to the previous node before it. Otherwise, how can the previous node  have its next pointer updated?

This inserts your node *after* an existing node:

```
p->next = g->edges[x]->next;
g->edges[x]->next = p;
```